# getting error: is not a function in postman

Tags: javascript, postman, chai

I am writing basic API tests with postman, I don't know why I am getting an error message for theses two test the message is the same : res.every is not a function and forEach is not a function

```
pm.test("All supplier users have uuid", function () {
const res = pm.response.json();
pm.expect(res.every(uuidIsDefined)).to.be.true; 

});

pm.test("Every item has id an from ids[]", () => {
response = pm.response.json();
response.forEach(element => pm.expect(element.id).to.be.oneOf(ids));
});
```

Comment: `res` and `response` aren't arrays.

Comment: no indeed they are  a json object, any idea how I can do the same with a json object?

Comment: Please add your response

Answer (score 0):

in fact I have an inner array in my json object, so I had to point into the array first. In case no array is present json has to be parsed:

```
pm.test("Test name", function () {
   const resp = pm.response.json();
   pm.expect(resp.results.every((res) => {
       return res.uuid != undefined;
   })).to.be.true;
   

});
```